# Fermat's Little Theorem: Understanding the collection of terms part.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I feel as if this question is an obvious answer but one that I am not seeing.

I am studying the proof of Fermat's Little Theorem. I have gotten up to the part in which we can rearrange the terms as multiplicatives of:

$[a],[2a],...,[(p-1)a] = [1],[2],...,[(p-1)]$.

From here, I am confused about the collection of these terms into this:

$(p-1)!a^{(p-1)} = (p-1)!$

More specifically, why is it not:

$(p-1)!a = (p-1)!$

Comment: because if one multiplies $a, 2a, 3a, \ldots, (p-1)a$, gets $(p-1)!a^{p-1}$, there are $p-1$ $a's$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left hand of your first equality you have

$$a\cdot(2a)\cdot\ldots\cdot((p-1)a)=a^{p-1}\cdot1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot(p-1)=a^{p-1}(p-1)!$$

(observe you multiply $\;a\;$ with itself $\;p-1\;$ times...!) , and on the right side there you simply have

$$1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot(p-1)=(p-1)!\;$$